# Different form bound on a Django Form What does it?

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Project where some old code is and I found a part where I'm not really know what it does.

Here

```
form = UserForm(request.REQUEST)
```

What I normally do is

```
form = UserForm(request.POST)
```

What is the difference between this both snippets. What does request.REQUEST in the form?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gives you either `request.POST` or `request.GET`, but not recommended to use.

From [`HttpRequest`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.REQUEST) reference

> HttpRequest.REQUEST
>
> For convenience, a dictionary-like object that searches POST first, then GET. Inspired by PHP’s $_REQUEST.
>
> For example, if GET = {"name": "john"} and POST = {"age": '34'},
> REQUEST["name"] would be "john", and REQUEST["age"] would be "34".
>
> It’s strongly suggested that you use GET and POST instead of REQUEST,
> because the former are more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

You could have looked up [the documentation for `request.REQUEST`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.REQUEST):

> For convenience, a dictionary-like object that searches POST first, then GET.

Perhaps the authors of this code did not know if the form would be submitted via POST or GET, so used REQUEST to make sure they caught both.